# JavaScript async/await and do/while loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, do-while, ecmascript-2016

The following script runs as expected when the outer loop iterates less than approx. 100 times. If the outer loop iterates a few thousand times, I can see that my console.log s are mixed up. For instance:

- 3x Outer loop output
- 1x Inner loop output
- 1x Outer loop output // Should not happen, as all outer loop
  outputs are before the inner    loop output!

...or...

- 3x Outer loop output
- 2x Inner loop output // Should not happen, as there is only one inner
  loop output!

...there are many other weird combinations, but I think it is always the same cause.

It seems that the combination of async/await and do/while loops do not work smoothly in my case. I have tried to get rid of the do/while loops by making separate recursive functions, but in vain. Is there another way of doing that? Any help is very appreciated.

```
async function asyncGenerator() {
  // other code
  do {
    // other code
    var fileList = await listFiles(nextPageToken);
    // other code
    do {
      // other code
      var parents = await requestParents(fileList.result.items[0].parents[0].id);
      // other code
    } while (response.result.parents[0].isRoot === false);
    // other code
  } while (fileList.result.nextPageToken !== "undefined")
  // other code
}

function listFiles(token) {
  return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
    'maxResults': sizeResults,
    'pageToken': token,
    'q': query
  });
}

function requestParents(fileId) {
  return gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': fileId
  });
}
```

EDIT:

- As requested, please find below the original code.
- I think you need to create a new google developers console project
  and insert the corresponding "clientId" and "apiKey".
- I exchanged the outer do/while loop in the meantime with a recursive
  function call, but the output is still strange.
- I was not sure how to include the browser.js and runtime.js,
  therefore the script-tags still contain my paths.
- In addition, I am not sure, if this is working in the snippet:
  type="text/babel" src="js/driverights.js" within the 4th script-tag.

```js
"use strict";

var driveRights = (function() {
  var clientId = 'YOUR CLIENT ID';
  var apiKey = 'YOUR API KEY';
  var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts';

  function handleClientLoad() {
    var initButton = document.getElementById('init');
    initButton.onclick = function() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
      window.setTimeout(checkAuth(false, handleAuthResult), 1);
    }
  }

  function checkAuth(imm, callback) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: clientId,
      scope: scopes,
      immediate: imm
    }, callback);
  }

  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
      gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', initialize);
    } else {
      $('#progress').html('Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen');
    }
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var timeOut = 120;
  var counter = 0;
  var tokenMemory;
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var currentTime;
  // Test data
  var sizeResults = 1;
  var parentFolders = ['0B11RmPttIhB3aFhaMzFQQ0Rjbm8', '0B6R9YDOGf_BUSC0wNW1lRWlnSmc', '0B6R9YDOGf_BUUHRoUW9tRkljUFk', '0B6R9YDOGf_BUfjc3QlZ1YU9Tb2lHcmhLVGhWc3FqSzE4S1dvZlhlLWd6aVFhUWdENWkyYkU'];
  var newUser = 'TEST@TEST.COM';
  var query = 'trashed = false';

  var initialize = function() {
    $('#start').click(function() {
      asyncGenerator();
    });
  };

  async function asyncGenerator(token) {
    try {
        // REQUEST FILES
        counter += sizeResults;
        tokenMemory = token;
        await sleep(timeOut);
        var fileList = await listFiles(token);
        console.log("Requested so far: ", counter);
        console.log("Number of received files: ", fileList.result.items.length);
        console.log(fileList);

        // END REACHED
        if (fileList.result.items.length === 0) {
          console.log("DONE - no more files");
          return;
        }

        // CHECK FILES
        var firstCheckResult = firstCheck(fileList.result.items[0]);
        // Rights
        if (firstCheckResult === "rights") {
          $('#progress').append(`Rechte | ${fileList.result.items[0].title} | ${fileList.result.items[0].owners[0].displayName} | ${fileList.result.items[0].alternateLink} <br>`);
          console.log("TO DO: rights");
        }
        // Check parents
        if (firstCheckResult === "checkParents") {
          var parentID = fileList.result.items[0].parents[0].id;
          do {
            console.log("Do while loop parents are not root");
            await sleep(timeOut);
            var response = await requestParents(parentID);
            parentID = response.result.parents[0].id;
          } while (response.result.parents[0].isRoot === false);
          var secondCheckResult = secondCheck(response);
        }
        // No change
        if (firstCheckResult === "notChange" || secondCheckResult === "notChange") {
          console.log("TO DO: not");
        }
        // Change
        if (firstCheckResult === "change" || secondCheckResult === "change") {
          console.log("TO DO: change");
          await sleep(timeOut);
          await requestPermissions(fileList.result.items[0].id);
        }

        // REFRESH TOKEN IF NECESSARY
        currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (currentTime > (start + 2700000)) {
          start = new Date().getTime();
          console.log("Restart asyncGenerator! Reason: Create new token");
          checkAuth(true, asyncGenerator);
        }

        // CHECK IF NEXT PAGE TOKEN EXISTS
        if (typeof fileList.result.nextPageToken !== "undefined") {
          asyncGenerator(fileList.result.nextPageToken);
        } else {
          console.log("DONE - no next page token");
        }

    // RESTART IF ERROR OCCURS
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.result.error.code === 500) {
        console.log("Restart asyncGenerator! Reason: Error 500");
        asyncGenerator(tokenMemory);
      }
      if (err.result.error.message.indexOf("Es ist ein interner Fehler aufgetreten, der die Freigabe") > -1) {
        console.log("Restart asyncGenerator! Reason: Permission Error");
        asyncGenerator(tokenMemory);
      }
    }
  }

  function listFiles(token) {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      'maxResults': sizeResults,
      'pageToken': token,
      'q': query
    });
  }

  function requestParents(fileId) {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      'fileId': fileId
    });
  }

  function requestPermissions(fileId) {
    return gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
      'fileId': fileId,
      'sendNotificationEmails': false,
      'resource': {
        'value': newUser,
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'writer',
        'name': 'Team'
      }
    });
  }

  function firstCheck(file) {
    // File can't be shared -> output to site
    if (file.writersCanShare === false) {
      return "rights";
    }
    // File is forbidden folder -> do not change
    else if (parentFolders.indexOf(file.id) > -1) {
      return "notChange";
    }
    // File is root-folder and has no parents -> do change
    else if (file.parents.length === 0 && parentFolders.indexOf(file.id) === -1) {
      return "change";
    }
    // Parent-folder of file is root-folder and parent-folder ist not a forbidden folder -> do change
    else if (file.parents[0].isRoot === true && parentFolders.indexOf(file.parents[0].id) === -1) {
      return "change";
    }
    // Parent-folder of file is a forbidden-folder -> do not change
    else if (parentFolders.indexOf(file.parents[0].id) > -1) {
      return "notChange";
    }
    // If none of these exceptions is met -> check parent
    else {
      return "checkParents";
    }
  }

  function secondCheck(file) {
    // If file's parent is one of the forbidden folders-> do not change
    if (parentFolders.indexOf(file.result.id) > -1) {
      return "notChange";
    } else {
      return "change";
    }
  }

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  return {
    start: handleClientLoad,
  };
})();

driveRights.start();
```

```css
.cover {
 margin: 5% 0;
 background: none;
}

.full {
  background: url(cover.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.coverbox {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) !important;
}

.separator {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}

#init, #start {
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Drive Rights</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/browser.js"></script>
 <script type="text/babel" src="js/driverights.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/runtime.js"></script>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="cover full">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron coverbox clearfix">
   <h1>Drive Rights</h1>
   <p>
    Change file permissions for specific user.
   </p>
   <hr class="separator">
   <div id="info" class="clearfix">
    <p>
     First click login, then start.
    </p>
    <p class="text-center">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="init">
      Login
     </button></br>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="start">
      Start
     </button>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="progress"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No, the loop is hardly the problem, `do while` works with `async/await` just as every other loop does (unless its transpilation is broken - can you show us the transpiled ES5 maybe?)

Comment: Where did you put your log statements? Can you post an example that we can easily run ourselves? Even complete code would help.

Comment: What does your actual output look like?

Comment: @trusktr: I changed my second version a little bit and now it is working. I still do not know why the async function did not work in combination with the two do/while loops, but I will keep it in mind and use recursive function calls instead.

Comment: Your `checkAuth` function still seems to take a callback instead of returning a promise.

Comment: When you are calling `asyncGenerator(…token…);` "recursively", that fires off a new asynchronous action which returns a promise. You'll need to `await` or `return` that result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a nested do-while loop in your `asyncGenerator` function, but I do see that `asyncGenerator` can be called recursively (sometimes indirectly), and during each call some new asynchronous `await`s happen. There is no guarantee that any of those `await` expressions will complete in the same order, and thus no guarantee that the `console.log` statements always be in order that they happen in the code. Some of your `await` expressions are relying on the network (f.e. `await listFiles(...)`) and the network isn't so predictable all the time. It's possible a request that started first might not finish first, so your recursive function calls won't always execute as expected.

One thing you can do to possibly fix this is to refactor your recursive calls to also use `await`, so the recursive calls might look like:

```
await asyncGenerator(fileList.result.nextPageToken);
```